# I moved WAMP to a different hdd drive on local computer...now wordpress doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wamp

i got a brainwave the other day that turned out to be a bad idea.
I needed to move stuff of my c:\ drive to an external to save space and decided to move WAMP to this external drive (H:) as well.

Now that i have done that, the localhost\Wordpress website i had on the WAMP doesnt work anymore.

So i am after advice and instructions on the following 2 things.

1. I imagine i could just reinstall WAMP (either back in its original location or on the external drive), copy the existing Wordpress files and database into it and things would work again?
2. I would also now like to learn how to manually get an existing install of WAMP + Wordpress to work after making said error. What is involved in manually changing the WAMP drive letter and directory?

kind regards
Adam

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What are the errors?

Comment: http://localhost/Wordpress returns a 404 error after moving WAMP to the external hdd. My understanding is that WAMP is the problem...in that i moved it to H:\ whilst most of apache's and i guess mysql links are still pointing at C:\WAMP\...

Comment: That's most likely the case. With just copy/pasting or moving, it didn't change the locations for anything. You could edit your httpd-vhosts.conf and try changing your `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` settings.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the solution that i think works best...

1. backup the wordpress directory (dont worry about anything above it in www unless there is something above that is needed)
2. export the mysql database
3. completely uninstall WAMP
4. rename/or remove any remaining WAMP files and folders
5. Reinstall WAMP
6. Go the thestandard Wordpress install procedure as outlined at wordpress.org with the following consideration:
    a. when asked to create a new database do so with same db name, username and password, table suffixes and server (localhost in my case) as your original database (this part is important)
7. Once the default wordpress install is up and running
8. copy your full backup wordpress directory into new Wordpress install replacing everything in that directory
9. import your original database backup using phpmyadmin into the new database you created in step 6 above.
10. log into the wp dashboard /wp-admin
11. reactivate all plugins and themes

viola.

Comment: Correct! You cannot copy a WAMP install from drive to drive as the drive letter you install WAMPServer onto is stored in number of the config files. This would apply to any Windows based AMP stack.

Comment: But you can move the site files from www to anywhere you like and then make a link to it from the original wamp folder. I do this for site folders as well as mysql data folders.